# REST API - Send back to Frontend instructions on what to show and how to continue the flow

Tags: rest, design-patterns, frontend, backend

In my platform UI, I have a form which allow the user to enter some personal information.
Such form must be different based on some generic parameter associated with the customer which the backend can infer from the customer id.

Given that, the Frontend service (responsible of showing the form to the user) sends a request to a backend service API to obtain a JSON representation of such form.

I have no issues with that.

The problem is that, apart from the form itself, the user flow will also change based on such discriminating parameter and I would like to find a way, for the backend, to include in the response body a "representation" of what the UI should look like apart from the static user form (whether there are buttons, how they are designed, their function when clicked, dropdown menus etc...).

Considering I would like to keep the frontend agnostic and as much dumb as possible, I am wondering whether there is an architectural pattern or standard I can follow for this kind of operation.